# Click on Button in child component only works once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Button inside a header component that can for some reason only be clicked once. In my HomeContainer I include a Header component. In that Header Component I included a button that should show another component when the button was clicked. This is working so far. But when I try to click the button again to change the displayed component again, the button is unclickable.

HomeContainer:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from "react-native";

import ButtonTest from "../../components/home/ButtonTest";
import RaidGroupOverview from "../../components/home/RaidGroupOverview";
import HeaderContainer from "../header/Header";
import AddRaidGroup from "../../components/home/AddRaidGroup";

class HomeContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showAddRaidGroup: false,
    };

    this.parentFunction = this.parentFunction.bind(this);
  }

  parentFunction = (data_from_child) => {
    console.log(data_from_child);
    console.log(this.state.showAddRaidGroup);
    this.setState({
      showAddRaidGroup: this.state.showAddRaidGroup === true ? false : true,
    });
    console.log(this.state.showAddRaidGroup);
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("I WILL UPDATE");
    console.log(this.state.showAddRaidGroup);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <HeaderContainer functionCallFromParent={this.parentFunction} />
        {!this.state.showAddRaidGroup ? (
          <RaidGroupOverview />
        ) : (
          <AddRaidGroup />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight + 30 || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "#f9c2ff",
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default HomeContainer;
```

Inside that HomeContainer I include a Header component that includes the Button:

```
import React from "react";
import { Header } from "react-native-elements";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import { ListItem, Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import ButtonTest from "../../components/home/ButtonTest";

class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.childFunction = this.childFunction.bind(this);
  }
  childFunction = (data) => {
    this.props.functionCallFromParent(data);
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("I WILL UPDATE");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Header
        placement="center"
        barStyle="light-content"
        leftComponent={
          <ButtonTest functionCallFromParent={this.childFunction} />
        }
        centerComponent={{ text: "test", style: { color: "#fff" } }}
        rightComponent={{ icon: "home", color: "#fff" }}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: "#3D6DCC",
          justifyContent: "space-around",
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default HeaderContainer;
```

And finally the button:

```
import React from "react";
import { ListItem, Icon, Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

class ButtonTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
      title: "Test",
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log("HI");
    if (!this.state.clicked) {
      this.setState({
        clicked: true,
        title: "Test1",
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        clicked: false,
        title: "Test",
      });
    }

    this.props.functionCallFromParent("Hello From Child1");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onPress={this.handleClick} title={this.state.title} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonTest;
```

I don´t understand why I can only click the button once. Any help would be great!

EDIT:

[image: Button state after clicked once]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "the button is unclickable"? is something adding the `disabled` prop?

Comment: I click the button once = Works. I want to click the same button again => It does not work anymore. No log is output

Comment: which console log? this one? `console.log("HI");` ?

Comment: Yes and also the logs from the parentComponent (HomeContainer), state changes and so on ` console.log(data_from_child);` Also the view is not changing as i´d expect#

Comment: And I can see from the dev-tools that the button is not disabled and still has the onPres function bound. I have added an image of the dev tools

Comment: is it possible that one of the child components is "on top" of your header due to styling issues? the code seems okay (other than lots of unnecessary duplicate functions). What if you only rendered the HeaderContainer, does it still not fire the logs then?

Comment: I think you were right. My component was the issue due to wrong styling. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @azium My Component that I inlcuded after clicking the button, had bad styling which leads to the issue that I could no longer click the button, because an invisible view was right before that. Thanks for your help!